# Python Pandas going through an entire column and checking if it contains a certain str

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm kinda new to python dataframes, so this might sound really easy. 
I have a column called 'body_text' in a dataframe and I want to see if each row of body_text contains the word "Hello". And if it does, I want to make another column that has 1 or 0 as the values.

I tried using `str.contains("Hello")` but that made an error where it only selected the rows that had "Hello" and attempted to put it in another column. 
I tried looking at other solutions that just ended up in more errors - for loops, and str in str.

```
textdf = traindf[['request_title','request_text_edit_aware']]
```

traindf is a huge dataframe that I'm only pulling 2 columns from

Comment: Please add your attempt and the error in an [edit]

Comment: Hi and welcome to the community. Remember to format code snippets (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) and take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples 
To answer the question properly we need to have an idea of what the dataframe looks like. From thee information you have provided us with, we don't know if you want to search multiple columns for 'hello', if we need to search for strings within a string or just for hello etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your match is case-sensitive, use [`Series.str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) and chain on [`.astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html) to cast as `int`:

```
df['contains_hello'] = df['body_text'].str.contains('Hello').astype(int)
```

If it should match, case-insensitive, added the `case=False` argument:

```
df['contains_hello'] = df['body_text'].str.contains('Hello', case=False).astype(int)
```

---

### Update

If you need to match multiple patterns, use `regex` with `|` *('OR')* character. You may also need a a *'word boundary'* character as well depending on your requirements.

[Regexr](https://regexr.com/) is a good resource if you want to learn more about `regex` patterns and character classes.

#### Example

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'body_text': ['no matches here', 'Hello, this should match', 'high low - dont match', 'oh hi there - match me']})

#                      body_text
#    0           no matches here   
#    1  Hello, this should match   <--  we want to match this 'Hello'
#    2     high low - dont match   <-- 'hi' exists in 'high', but we don't want to match it
#    3    oh hi there - match me   <--  we want to match 'hi' here

df['contains_hello'] = df['body_text'].str.contains(r'Hello|\bhi\b', regex=True).astype(int)

                  body_text  contains_hello
0           no matches here               0
1  Hello, this should match               1
2     high low - dont match               0
3    oh hi there - match me               1
```

Sometimes it's useful to have a `list` of words you want to match, to create a `regex` pattern more easily with a python [`list comprehension`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). For example:

```
match = ['hello', 'hi']    
pat = '|'.join([fr'\b{x}\b' for x in match])
# '\bhello\b|\bhi\b'  -  meaning 'hello' OR 'hi'

df.body_text.str.contains(pat)
```

Comment: In the case of multiple characters, how would you implement it? Like I wanted it to also include "Hi" as a string to check for. Thanks for answering!

Comment: @MeiTei I've updated my answer, I hope that it helps.

Answer (score 0):

With textdf as you've defined in your question, try:

```
textdf['new_column'] = [1 if t == 'Hello' else 0 for t in textdf['body_text'] ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `get_dummies()` function in Panda.

[Here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) is the link to documentation.